# Работа с bluetooth

Tags: java, c++, c, bluetooth

Я долго искал информацию в интернете, но не нашёл самого простого: работа с bluetooth (конкретно то, что мне нужно). Я работал с сокетами python и с другими библиотеками, но всё тщетно. Мне нужен код, который просто отправляет запрос на подключение к устройству (пока что без клиента). Код нужно сделать на C или C++, можно даже Java. Нужно чтобы запрос шел только на bluetooth адрес, без каких либо дополнительных данных.

Comment: в голом Си/С++ из коробки никакой поддержки синезуба нет... или выбери какую-либо стороньюю библиотеку, или смотри как это сделать конкретно под твоей ОС...

Comment: а что с java ? Там же есть встроенная НЕ ЗАВИСИМАЯ от платформы поддержка блютуза?

Comment: про java ничего не скажу... могу только предложить подождать тех, кто знает или обратиться к гуглу...

Comment: Специально для него есть транспортный протокол в сокетах. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-programming-with-windows-sockets

Comment: Это для Java? Или C/C++?

Comment: А какая вам разница для какого языка? Сокеты Беркли, они и в Африке сокеты Беркли.